# It is possible to install ASM Grid Standalone without creating a DATA diskgroup first. It seem ohasd need to be install first

Tags: oracle, oracle-grid-control

I have installed OEM grid standalone and have it working fine.  However I would like to install GRID without having to create the DATA group first. In other words install ASM software using a local spfile and password file and then using sqlplus as sysasm create the first disk group and others

I tried a software install of grid, but it would not let me start asm because there was no ohasd or css(something).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. If you omit certain values in HAS response .rsp file (like diskgroup name), HAS will be silently installed, but ASM instance wont get created.

You can leave it as it is, and you can use HAS to manage databases having datafiles in FS. Or you can create ASM instance by your own manually.